# Efficiently check whether each column in a PyTorch tensor has a corresponding reversed column

Tags: python, pytorch, reverse, tensor

I have a collection of tensors of common shape `(2,ncol)`. Example:

```
torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3, 7, 8], [3, 3, 1, 8, 7]], dtype=torch.long)
```

For each tensor, I want to determine if, for each column `[[a], [b]]`, the reversed column `[[b], [a]]` is also in the tensor. For example, in this case, since `ncol` is odd, I can immediately say that this is not the case. But in this other example

```
torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 4], [3, 3, 1, 8, 7, 2]], dtype=torch.long)
```

I would actually have to perform the check. A naive solution would be

```
test = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 4], [3, 3, 1, 8, 7, 2]], dtype=torch.long)

def are_column_paired(matrix: torch_geometric.data.Data) -> bool:
    ncol = matrix.shape[1]
    if ncol % 2 != 0:
        all_paired = False
        return all_paired

    column_has_match = torch.zeros(ncol, dtype=torch.bool)
    for i in range(ncol):
        if column_has_match[i]:
            continue
        column = matrix[:, i]
        j = i + 1
        while not (column_has_match[i]) and (j <= (ncol - 1)):
            if column_has_match[j]:
                j = j + 1
                continue
            current_column = matrix[:, j]
            current_column = current_column.flip(dims=[0])
            if torch.equal(column, current_column):
                column_has_match[i], column_has_match[j] = True, True
            j = j + 1

    all_paired = torch.all(column_has_match).item()

    return all_paired
```

But of course this is slow and possibly not pythonic. How can I write a more efficient code?

PS note that while `test` here is very small, in the actual use case I expect `ncol` to be O(10^5).

Comment: Does each column have to have distinct elements? Otherwise, the condition could hold even when ncol is odd, e.g. [[1],[1]].

Comment: @GoodDeeds good question. Let's exclude self-loops for now (in other words, let's assume that there are no columns `[[a], [b]]` such that `a=b`).

Comment: Also, is there any constraint on what the values can be? Are they integers within some range? (From your comment on self loops, I guess this is a graph whose edge connections you are looking at?)

Comment: 1) Yes, they're integers 2) no, there's no range 3) yes, these are graphs I'm looking at (I need to process a sequence of tensors, and each tensor is a separate graph).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible simple approach. It is likely not the most efficient you can get, but is much faster than your current solution. The idea is to simply check if the sorting the columns in the original and row-flipped tensors are identical. I believe the time complexity of this approach is `O(n logn)`, as opposed to `O(n^2)` in your case.

```
def are_columns_paired(matrix):
    flipped_matrix = matrix.flip(dims=[0])
    matrix_sorted = matrix[:,matrix[1].argsort()] # sort second row
    matrix_sorted = matrix_sorted[:, matrix_sorted[0].sort(stable=True)[1]] # sort first row, keeping positions in second row fixed when there is a tie
    flipped_matrix = flipped_matrix[:,flipped_matrix[1].argsort()]
    flipped_matrix = flipped_matrix[:, flipped_matrix[0].sort(stable=True)[1]]
    return (matrix_sorted == flipped_matrix).all()
```

Here, for both the original and flipped matrix, we sort the columns, first based on the first row, and when there is a tie, based on the second row.

I tested both approaches on a randomly generated tensor with `ncol=2000000` and values ranging from 0 to 999999. The above code ran in about 1 second, while the approach from the question did not provide a solution even after an hour.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working? I tried it with this tensor `torch.tensor([[0, 1, 1, 2], [1, 0, 2, 1]], dtype=torch.long)` and it returns `False`, while it should return `True`. My crappy approach returns `True` (BTW, I edited the approach in order to reduce the number of unnecessary comparisons, but I think it's still `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @DeltaIV Sorry, there was a typo. Should work now.

Comment: Great! Could you just add a bit of explanation on what the code does? If I understand correctly, when you say "sort second row", you're moving the whole columns, so that the association between first and second row doesn't break. Is that correct?

Comment: @DeltaIV Yes. For both the original and flipped matrix, we sort the columns, first based on the first row, and when there is a tie, based on the second row.

Comment: @DeltaIV BTW, this assumes that there are no duplicate entries for the same edge. If there are two instances of [[a],[b]] but only one of [[b],[a]], this would return False.

Comment: Good point. But a decent edge index shouldn't contain the same edge, in the same direction, twice! I may add some data validation outside this method, that checks that there are no duplicate edges. But I have a more pressing question: how did you come up with this method? I would have never thought of that. Do you have any (preferably short) references that could help me find such efficient solutions in the future?

Comment: A pattern that I can see, is that you substituted a for loop (actually, **two** for loops) with sorting, and we have efficient algorithms for sorting. Is that a pattern I should look for? When I see nested loops, see if I can substitute it with sorting?